# why does my isFull function is always return 1?

Tags: c, queue

I made a function to check if my circular queue is full, but it always return 1 (aka "true");

this is my Queue setup:

```
    #define MAX_LENGTH 150

typedef double ElementType;
typedef int bool;

typedef struct
{
    ElementType Elements[MAX_LENGTH];
    int front;
    int rear;
} Queue;
```

and this is my function:

```
int isFull(Queue Q)
{
    if (Q.front == Q.rear++)
        return 1;
    if ((Q.rear == MAX_LENGTH) && (Q.front == 0))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

This function always return 1 mean the queue is full even though i have not put anything in the queue yet.

how do I fix this?
Thanks.

Edit:
I edited `Q.rear++` to `Q.rear+1`
Here is how I initialize the Queue.

```
void resetQueue(Queue *Q)
{
    Q->front = -1;
    Q->rear = -1;
};
```

I found out that the problem is right at:

```
if (Q.front == Q.rear+1)
        return 1;
```

part.

Now I just can put 2 Elements in the queue, if I put the third Elements, it will become full.

Comment: `Q.rear++` in the condition is asking for trouble. That will modify `Q.rear` *every* time you call `isFull`. Why do you have `++` here? A function like `isFull` shouldn't modify `front` or `rear` at all. Although in this case it's not as bad as it might seem, because `Q` is passed by value, it's a local copy so the modification doesn't propagate to the actual `Queue` object. Though making the copy is expensive, which is why you normally use pointers instead (but then the increment becomes dangerous).

Comment: Also relevant: How do you initialize the `Queue` structure? Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: You probably mean `Q.read+1`. That adds 1 without modifying the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of your problem, please learn the difference between prefix `++` and postfix `++` (i.e. between `++Q.rear` and `Q.rear++`).

Since you initialize both `front` and `rear` to the same value, the comparison `Q.front == Q.rear++` will be *true*, because the increment happens *after* the value of `Q.rear` is used.

The code

```
if (Q.front == Q.rear++)
{
    // ...
}
```

is really more equivalent to

```
int old_value_of_rear = Q.rear;
Q.rear = Q.rear + 1;

if (Q.front == old_value_of_rear)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you want to compare `Q.front` with `Q.rear + 1`, use that exact addition:

```
if (Q.front == Q.rear + 1)
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, I have just learned coding for 1 year so I need cultivating so much.
In this case, I setup the queue run backward (add new element at rear and delete element at front) so when I check if it full, the comparison become (Q.front+1 == Q.rear). This is my mistake LOL.